# Floating point exception

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int populate_primes(int array[])
{   
    const int max = 1000000; 
    char numbers[max+1];
    int count=1;
    array[0]=2;
    for(int i=max;i>0;i-=2)numbers[i]=0;
    for(int i=max-1;i>0;i-=2)numbers[i]=1;
    int i;  
    for(i=3;i*i<=max;i+=2){
        if(numbers[i]){
            for(int j=i*i;j<max+1;j+=i)numbers[j]=0;            array[count++]=i;
        }
    }
    int limit = max/2;
    for(;i<limit;i++)   if(numbers[i])array[count++]=i;
    return count;
}

int factorize(int number,int array[])
{
    int i=0,factor=1;
    while(number>0){
        if(number%array[i]==0){
            factor++;
            while(number%array[i]==0)number/=array[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",factor);
    return factor;
}
int main()
{
    int primes[42000];
    const int max = 1000000;
    int factors[max+1];
    clock_t start = clock();
    int size = populate_primes(primes);
    factorize(1000,primes);
    printf("Execution time:\t%lf\n",(double)(clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to find the no. of factors using simple algo. The populate primes part is running okay , but the factorize part does not execute and gives the floating point exception error.

Please see the code and tell my mistake.

Comment: check for array out of bounds? And array[i] != 0

Comment: Probably caused by `number%array[i]==0`, when `array[i]` is `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the size which you got from populate to factorize. 
factorize(int number, int array[], int size); 
problem is your array[] is not fully loaded, it is loaded only till size variable. So you may want to check for that. 
Also the logic inside factorize is wrong. You need to check (number > 1) rather than (number >0).

Comment: number>1 was the problem here .

Answer (score 1):

In your factorize method you access array[0], because the initial value of i is 0.
This array is the primes array which is populated by populate_primes. But populates prime doesn't write to primes[0], since the initial value of count is 1.

Thus the first element is not initialized and you probably get a div by 0 error.

Comment: I have initialized array[0]=2; separately thus that should not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the function below to see some problems:

```
#define MAX_PRIMES 42000
int factorize(int number,int array[])
{
  int i=0,factor=1;
  for (i=0; number>0 && i< MAX_PRIMES; i++){
    if (array[i] == 0 || array[i] == 1) {
      printf("Error: array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
    } else {
      if(number%array[i]==0){
        factor++;
        while(number%array[i]==0 && number>0) {
          printf("%d %d\n", number, array[i]);
          number/=array[i];
        }
      }   
    }   
  }
  printf("%d\n",factor);
  return factor;
}
```